Draw chart in .prpt file using Java API and pentaho
How can I draw a chart in .prpt format using Java API and pentaho?
I'm using pentaho files (.prpt) and Java API to create reports. Data is being sent using Angular and hql with .prpt and pdf files created automatically.
Now I want to draw a simple bar chart with this data but I can't find any resource or help for this.
How i can solve this problem?
 public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getReport(OutputStream out, Map<String, Object> parametersMap) {
        Reporter rep = new Reporter();

        String queryStr = "select sh.activityAsset.id as ID, " +
            "count(sh.id) as countHistory " +
            "from MAIServiceHistory sh " +
            "where " +
            "sh.activityAsset.id < 172 " +
            "group by sh.activityAsset.id " +
            "order by sh.activityAsset.id ";

        List<Object[]> list = manager.createQuery(queryStr, Object[].class).getResultList();

        return rep.getPDFReport("com/tida/mai/core/reports/test2.prpt", out, manager,queryStr, parametersMap);
    }

public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getPDFReport(String reportAddress, OutputStream out, EntityManager manager, String query,Map<String, Object> parametersMap) {
        try {
            String filename = "output.pdf";
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(getReports(reportAddress, out, manager, query, parametersMap));
            byte[] contents = IOUtils.toByteArray(fileInputStream);
            
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
            headers.setContentDispositionFormData("file", filename);
            headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

            return new ResponseEntity<>(contents, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public File getReports(String reportAddress, OutputStream out, EntityManager manager, String query, Map<String, Object> parametersMap) {
        ClassicEngineBoot.getInstance().start();
        final MasterReport report = createReportDefinition(reportAddress, manager, query, parametersMap);
        if (report != null) {
            report.setAttribute("http://reporting.pentaho.org/namespaces/engine/attributes/core",
                    "complex-text", "true");
        }


        try {
            // Run the report and save the HTML output to a byte stream
            // file.set.setContentType("application/pdf"); // Change to "application/pdf" for PDF output
            // Use the HtmlReportUtil to generate the report to a Stream HTML
            // HtmlReportUtil.createStreamHTML(report, out);
            // NOTE: Changing this to use PDF is simple:
            // 1. Change the above setContent call to use "application/pdf"
            // 2. Instead of HtmlReportUtil, use the following line:

            if (report != null) {
                PdfReportUtil.createPDF(report, out);
            }
        } catch (ReportProcessingException rpe) {
            rpe.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    private MasterReport createReportDefinition(String reportUrl, EntityManager manager, String query, Map<String, Object> parametersMap) {
        // Create a report using the autogenerated fields
        try {
            final ClassLoader classloader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
            final URL reportDefinitionURL = classloader.getResource(reportUrl);
            ResourceManager managerRes = new ResourceManager();
            managerRes.registerDefaults();
            Resource res = managerRes.createDirectly(reportDefinitionURL, MasterReport.class);
            MasterReport report = (MasterReport) res.getResource();
            DataRow dr = new ParameterDataRow(parametersMap.keySet().toArray(new String[0]), parametersMap.values().toArray());
            report.getParameterValues().putAll(dr);
            
            Session session = (Session) manager.getDelegate();
            session = session.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            StaticSessionProvider sessionProvider = new StaticSessionProvider(session);
            HQLDataFactory factory = new HQLDataFactory(sessionProvider);
            factory.setQuery("default", query);
            report.setDataFactory(factory);

            return report;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


